# Convert from Double to String in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert a value from Double to String in an Android Activity.I can get this to work with my first example here below (working in the sense of no squigly error from Eclipse). However I am curious as to why the second example is not working.

First example

```
balance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCardBalance);
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.getExtras() != null) {                           
    balance.setText(String.valueOf((long)intent.getDoubleExtra("balance", 0.00)));
}
```

Second example below not working (Error: "Cannot cast from Double to Long"

```
balance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCardBalance);
Double cardBalance;

Intent intent = getIntent();

if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
    cardBalance = intent.getDoubleExtra("balance", 0.00);
    balance.setText(String.valueOf((long)cardBalance);  
}
```

Would anyone know how I can get the second example to work as I need to log the value retrieved from the intent before passing it to the TextView.

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to cast from the `Double` object to a `long` primitive, which doesn't really make sense... What happens if you use `double`, with a lowercase "d"?

Comment: Ok, what should I use then? the value returned from the intent contains decimals and I read that using Double is for decimals is best practice

Comment: Doubles have decimal points, longs do not, so you actually cannot represent a double as a long. Definitely in this case as you are doing monetary stuff.

Comment: Ok, how can I convert the value from Double to String, Textview.SetText accepts Strings

Comment: As I said, what happens if you use `double` with a lowercase "d"?

Comment: Wow!, that worked, changing to double with the lowercase worked, thanks

Comment: Why not just add an empty string to the value in the textview?

Comment: General point, for monetary values you should not use double, for general decimals yes, for monetary values there is a special type BigDecimal see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you do this?

```
balance.setText(cardBalance + "");
```

Comment: Hmmm, very interesting that worked too? what was achieved by adding an empty string?

Comment: It creates a new String object by concatenating the value in cardBalance and the empty String.

Comment: @Val Okafor if this worked I would accept it, this is a technique a lot of people use, simple and clean.

Comment: It does work but it feels like a code smell to me. I would stick with String.valueOf() personally. This answer is not the way Java likes to work, you are abusing an implicit cast included for convenience. It feels more Javascriptesque.

Answer (score 1):

```
String yourDoubleString = String.valueOf(yourDouble);
```

in your case:

```
String yourDoubleString = String.valueOf(intent.getDoubleExtra("balance", 0.00));
```

Answer (score 0):

using String v = ""+String.valueOf((long)cardBalance) not work?

Comment: you cannot cast double to long, it would lose precision.

Comment: @feldoh You technically *can*, just not implicitly.

Comment: @user3580294 But you don't have the decimal part in a long, this is not an implicit cast, it is an explicit one. I know it's the same number of bits so 'could' pack the bits into a long if you wanted, but why would you? You could I suppose multiply up especially in this case; because it is monetary *100 would be sufficient to catch all decimals so then you could truncate it. Guava of course has functions to round a double to a long: `long DoubleMath.roundToLong(double x, RoundingMode mode)` but given that this is for a bank balance, rounding is certainly not the right answer.

Comment: @feldoh I'm just saying you *can* cast `double` to `long`.

Comment: @user3580294 fair enough